# What is the fastest way of extracting indexes of non "-1"s from an array?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a numpy array with dimension 1500 x 3300. I want to fetch indexes of all values which have value greater than 0.40.

For example a sub-array:

```
a = [0,0.5,0.4,-1,-1,0.9,0.3,-1,0.7]
```

Desired result:
    [0,1,5,8]

I have written the following code, but it takes a lot of time to run. It takes 20 minutes to run on an array of dimension 1500 x 3300.

```
def non_zero(lst):
    """ return indexes of items which are not -1 and value is greater than 0.40 """
    return [i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e > 0.40]
```

What can be the fastest alternative to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np    
np.where(np.array(a) > 0.40)[0].tolist()
```

values > 0.40 are ofcourse > -1

Also Iam assuming that "*a*" is a list of numbers (not a list of lists)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following directly in the 2D array:

```
i, j = np.where(np.array(lst) > 0.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.argwhere` to get the indexes.

```py
import numpy as np
idx = np.argwhere(a != -1 & a > 0.4)
```

And of course, a!= -1 is not necessary..